# ajaxで要素を動的に追加した際に、onsen UIのcssが効かない

Tags: monaca, onsen-ui, ajax

アプリ開発初心者です。
monaca, onsen UIを使用して開発をしております。

具体的には、ajaxを使ってデータベースにアクセスし、値の取り出しに成功した場合は指定したタグに要素を追加して表示させるといったプログラムを組もうとしております。
値の取り出しに成功して表示するまではうまくいくのですが、動的にタグに要素を追加した場合、onsen UIで設定してあるcssがうまく効かず、ただ文字列が列挙されてしまいます。
動的に追加した要素に予め設定してあるcssを適用させるにはどのようにしたら良いのか、ご挙示頂ければ幸いです。
よろしくお願い申し上げます。

以下が該当するコードになります。

scriptタグ内

```
(function(){
　'use strict';
　$(document).on('pageinit', '#top-page', function() {
　　$('#list_up', this).on('click', function() {
　　　new_list();
　　　app.navi.pushPage('list.html');
　　});
　});
})();

function new_list(){
　var data = {・・・}
　$.post("url", data).done(function(result){
　　var list = document.getElementById('list');
　　var onsrowNode = document.createElement('ons-row');
　　var onscolNode = document.createElement('ons-col');
　　var onscolNode2 = document.createElement('ons-col');
　　var textNode = document.createTextNode('温泉');
　　var textNode2 = document.createTextNode(result);
　　onscolNode.appendChild(textNode);
　　onscolNode2.appendChild(textNode2);
　　onsrowNode.appendChild(onscolNode);
　　onsrowNode.appendChild(onscolNode2);
　　list.appendChild(onsrowNode);
　}).fail(function(){
　　・・・
　});
}
```

以下body内

```
<ons-navigator page="top.html" var="app.navi"></ons-navigator>
<ons-template id="top.html">
　<ons-page id="top-page">
　　<ons-list-item modifier="chevron" class="item" id="list_up">
　　　<ons-row>
　　　　<ons-col class="title">
　　　　　<header>
　　　　　　<span class="item-title">リスト</span>
　　　　　</header>
　　　　</ons-col>
　　　</ons-row>
　　</ons-list-item>
　　・・・
　</ons-page>
</ons-template>

<ons-template id="list.html">
　<ons-page id="list-page">
　　<ons-list>
　　　<ons-list-item>
　　　　<div id="list"></div>
　　　</ons-list-item>
　　</ons-list>
　</ons-page>
</ons-template>
```

Comment: CSSの内容も教えてください。静的な要素では適用できていますか？

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/27274

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OnsenUI の `<ons-xxx>` といったコンポーネントは、実際にはより多くのタグや属性で構成されています。将来的には Custom Elements という形でブラウザが直接サポートすることになるようですが、現状では Javascript を使ってコンポーネントの定義を展開する必要があります。

```
<!-- ons.compile前 -->
<ons-button>Push Page</ons-button>

<!-- ons.compile後 -->
<ons-button class="ng-isolate-scope button effeckt-button slide-left">
  <span class="label ons-button-inner"><span class="ng-scope">Push Page</span></span>
  <span class="spinner button__spinner "></span>
</ons-button>
```

最初からHTMLに書かれているものは `ons.bootstrap()` 時にこの処理が行われますが、後から追加した要素については `ons.compile()` を使って手動で行う必要があります。

```js
ons.bootstrap();
ons.ready(function(){
  var outer = document.getElementById('hoge');
  
  var btn1 = document.createElement('ons-button');
  btn1.innerHTML = 'without compile()';
  outer.appendChild(btn1);
  
  var btn2 = document.createElement('ons-button');
  btn2.innerHTML = 'with compile()';
  outer.appendChild(btn2);
  ons.compile(btn2); // compileはappendChildしてから
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.3.11/build/css/onsenui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.3.11/build/css/onsen-css-components.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.3.11/build/js/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.3.11/build/js/onsenui.min.js"></script>

<ons-navigator>
  <ons-page>
    <div id="hoge"></div>
  </ons-page>
</ons-navigator>
```

参考 [AngularJSを意識せずにOnsen UIを扱う - Onsen UI Guide](http://ja.onsen.io/guide/overview.html#UsingOnsenUIwithjQueryorwithanyJSframeworks)

Comment: ご教示頂きまして、ありがとうございます。
無事にons-row/ons-colを適用できました。

一方で、以下のようにスタイルを適用しようとしても反映されませんでした。アイディア頂ければ幸いです。
btn2.style.cssText = 'width: 100px;';

新規で質問すべきでしょうか？？

Comment: @orobianco こちらで試すと `btn2.innerHTML=...` の直後に書いても `ons.compile(btn2)` の直後に書いても、指定通り幅が狭くなりましたが・・・。再度お試しいただいてもそうなってしまうなら、そのサンプルを添えて別途質問していただいた方がよいかと思います。

Comment: ご返信ありがとうございます。
もう一度試してみましたが、ダメでした。。。
再度質問しなおします。
今後とも宜しくお願い申し上げます。

Comment: @orobianco 了解しました。とりあえずこちらの質問に関しては解決したということであれば、回答左側のチェックマークで解決済みマークを付けていただけるとありがたいです。 http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/q/1735/8000